# Connect bluetooth to Allflex Livestock pocket reader deivce not working

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, rfid

I am developing mobile application which support both android and ios platform . and we are using Allflex livestock pocket reader to scan and i want to get that scanned data in mobile application through Bluetooth connection so can please tell there is any npm or library or sdk to connect Allfelx livestock pocket reader to mobile phone

Comment: I'm not sure if it's going to work with your reader as I use different one but try this https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager in my case It allows me to read and send data to reader

Comment: hi i am not able to get name of the connected bluetooth device

Comment: Were you able to complete this integration?